# Are "driver.refresh()" and "driver.get(current_url)" the same?

Tags: python, selenium

Title is all.

I think, as result, they are same function.

Are "driver.refresh()" and "driver.get(current_url)" the perfecly same?

Answer (score 0):

Refresh is same as browser refresh. It just reloads the same `url`. The `get('url')` option is equivalent of typing out an `url` in `urlbar` and pressing enter. Selenium waits for the website to be loaded before executing next script.